# Calling a method from a view

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have an Index view.  On this view is a link, and it is created like this:

```
<%= Html.ActionLink("Clear All", "ClearAll", "CachedCollections") %>
```

I don't want to have a view for ClearAll, I just want it to go in the method, clear what it needs to clear and then post back to the Index view.  How would I do this?  Do I need to call a method for this?

EDIT:

Here is my code:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ClearAll()
{
   Debug.Print("Got to here");

   return RedirectToAction("Index", CachedDictionaryCollectionManager.List);
}
```

From my action link it's not hitting this action method.  It just tells me that the resource is not found when I click on it.

Please advise.

Thanks.

Comment: it would be nice if you would also put the names of the controllers, so that we could know which action/view to which controller belongs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the called action you return RedirectToAction("Index");

```
public ActionResult ClearAll()
{
   ...
   return RedirectToAction("Index","Home");
   //Home is the controller name, don't specify it if you redirect to an action from the same controller
}
```

Comment: I've got this part, I've marked the method as HttpPost. When I click on the link then it says to me The resource cannot be found. I have a breakpoint in and it doesn't even go into the method.

Comment: @Brendan Vogt it doesn't go there because a click on a link is not a post (usually), so you either remove the [HttpPost] or you put a form method="post" action="<%=Url("Action","Controller")%>" with a submit button  instead of the Html.ActionLink

Answer (score 2):

In your ClearAll method at the end just put:

return View("Index");

Answer (score 1):

Action methods don't really need to return anything:

Use: `Return new EmptyResult();`